# Counting lines of text and get color of a specific line in an image

Tags: .net, image-manipulation, image-processing

check this picture out before I explain further:
[image]
How can I count the amount of lines there are from the yellow line to line #5? OCR sounds like overkill, because I don't really care what the text says.

Answer (score 3):

Rough outline:

- scan your image horizontally, pixel-line wise
- each pixel line eithers contains only black pixels, or some white/yellow pixels: store this information in a boolean array.
- group the pixel line numbers together, each sequence of non-empty lines and each sequence of empty lines form a group. The non-empty line groups represent the word lines, and the empty-line groups represent the space between the word lines.
- so what remains is simply counting the groups

To deal with aliasing effects, you will probably have to refine this a little bit, for example, by interpreting pixel lines as empty when they contain only a few number of white pixels, or by expecting a minimum size for any group (see Lars Viklund's comment) . You will have to adapt this to the quality and resolution of your images.

Comment: A reason for a minimum group size may be diacritics adjacent to but not connected to the base glyph of the grapheme. Even in the US alphabet, you've got lowercase `i`.

Comment: @LarsViklund Unless you have some degenerate case (`ijijij`), it is likely that there is at least one pixel on each line.